# The entity was not found

Tags: azure

Following this [Microsoft tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-linux-cli-sample-create-vm-from-snapshot?toc=%2Fcli%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json) to create a VM from a snapshot I receive the error message

`The entity was not found.`

but I do not have idea what this error means. Moreover is poorly documented this error, any idea?

Comment: Which line generated that message?

Comment: sorry I created this question because the error message is badly documented, so I proposed my solution, in order to help other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is incomplete; indeed this error is raised by `az disk create` because has not been specified the location of the snapshot.

So in my case was necessary to add `--location westeurope` parameter to the previous command and it worked.

`az disk create --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $osDiskName --sku $storageType --size-gb $diskSize --source $snapshotId --location westeurope`